# How long would a Groupon-like site take to be developed by a reasonably experienced php developer?

Tags: php

Including a basic design, how many hours do you think it would take to build a daily deals site in php?

Comment: 37 thousand years!!!!!!!!!!!!!! moo haha

Comment: By just 1 developer? I think @Neal is pretty close in his estimate :)

Comment: `<html><head><title>Groupon!</title><body></body></html>` There. It's done. a few more details to fill in and it can IPO.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you used a DMS like drupal you could do it in a few days, but unfortunately, those things are all over the place and you also need real-world contacts to make such a business work.

(For the sceptics)
Hook a node type that allows voting up to the trigger/event system and tada. Also require a small army of maintainers.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how elaborate its going to be.

If you're looking for a mirror of groupon's features you will need a dedicated team of devs/engineers for maintaining the website and hardware.